# How to add custom scripts while making a LiveCD customization

Tags: software-center, live-cd, scripts

I want to add custom scripts while making a customization of an Ubuntu LiveCD.

Comment: Hi aditya. I'm sorry, this is a bit unclear. What kind of custom scripts? To be run when? Before install? During? In regular use? To accomplish what, concretely? Please edit your post with more details, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My stock answer for this question is [this](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/convert-vm-iso) article over on Turnkeylinux's blog.  It's an Ubuntu derived distro and they have a physical to live set of scripts in their repo that works pretty well.  Bonus, you can install their scripts on Ubuntu mainline.

There's also remastersys and a couple others, but I found the turnkey scripts to be really straightforward for my needs.

The article:
Converting a virtual disk image: VDI or VMDK to an ISO you can distribute
By Alon Swartz - 58 comments | Latest by unit

## Why would anyone in their right mind want to convert a VM into an ISO?

Good question, the answer for Conor Fox (who was the inspiration for this post - thanks Conor!) was to distribute his customized TurnKey PostgreSQL image so others could use it.

Distributing an ISO as opposed to a VM image allows it to be installed on any virtualization platform, as well as on bare metal, with the added bonus of running live.

I suppose that's a good enough reason, so lets get to it.

## Convert VM disk to raw image and mount it

First we need to get qemu-img, a tool bundled with qemu (KVM's virtualization backend) to convert the VM disk to a raw image, and TKLPatch, the TurnKey customization mechanism to package the ISO.

If you are not using a TurnKey installation, see the [TKLPatch installation notes](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/tklpatch/installation).

`apt-get install qemu

apt-get install tklpatch`

I'll show how to convert a VMWare VMDK image into raw disk format. If you are using a different virtualization platform such as Virtualbox, see [this post](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/convert-vdi-vmdk) on converting a VDI to a raw image.

`qemu-img convert -f vmdk turnkey-core.vmdk -O raw turnkey-core.raw`

Next, mount the raw disk as a loopback device.

mkdir turnkey-core.mount
mount -o loop turnkey-core.raw turnkey-core.mount

**GOTCHA 1**: If your VM has partitions, it's a little tricker. You'll need to setup the loop device, partition mappings and finally mount the rootfs partition. You will need kpartx to setup the mappings.

```
loopdev=$(losetup -s -f turnkey-core.raw)

apt-get install kpartx
kpartx -a $loopdev

# p1 refers to the first partition (rootfs)
mkdir turnkey-core.mount
mount /dev/mapper/$(basename $loopdev)p1 turnkey-core.mount
```

## Extract root filesystem and tweak for ISO configuration

Now, make a copy of the root filesystem and unmount the loopback.

```
mkdir turnkey-core.rootfs
rsync -a -t -r -S -I turnkey-core.mount/ turnkey-core.rootfs

umount -d turnkey-core.mount
```

## If your VM had partitions (GOTCHA 1):

kpartx -d $loopdev
losetup -d $loopdev

Because the VM is an installed system as opposed to the ISO, the file system table needs to be updated.

```
cat>turnkey-core.rootfs/etc/fstab<<EOF
aufs / aufs rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
EOF
```

**GOTCHA 2**: If your VM uses a kernel optimized for virtualization (like the one included in the TurnKey VM builds), you need to replace it with a generic kernel, and also remove vmware-tools if installed.

```
tklpatch-chroot turnkey-core.rootfs

# inside the chroot
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-generic
dpkg --purge $(dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}\n' -W 'vmware-tools*')
dpkg --purge $(dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}\n' -W '*-virtual')

exit
```

## Generate the ISO

Finally, prepare the cdroot and generate the ISO.

```
tklpatch-prepare-cdroot turnkey-core.rootfs/
tklpatch-geniso turnkey-core.cdroot/
```

Thats it!

Bonus: By default the ISO will boot automatically. If you want to include the TurnKey bootsplash and bootmenu, extract the cdroot from a TurnKey ISO and tell tklpatch-prepare-cdroot to use it as a template.

```
tklpatch-extractiso turnkey-core.iso
tklpatch-prepare-cdroot turnkey-core.rootfs/ turnkey-core.cdroot/
tklpatch-geniso turnkey-core.cdroot/
```