# Updating Packages on Ubuntu Alternate CD

Tags: installation, package-management

Is there any way to update the packages on an Ubuntu install CD? I have a customized alternate install CD (to automatically install Ubuntu and set it up for me), and I would like to update all the default packages that are installed for ease of deployment reasons.

In the Windows world, you could do this with various tools and they called it slipstreaming. I am using 11.04, so the daily builds that Ubuntu has will not work for me, as they only seem to support Lucid and Precise at the moment.

I have looked at UCK (Ubuntu Customization Kit), but it only seems to work for adding packages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add custom scripts while making a LiveCD customization](http://askubuntu.com/questions/113427/how-to-add-custom-scripts-while-making-a-livecd-customization)

Comment: That post is only vaguely similar to what I am asking in that we are both asking about install CDs. I just need to update the packages on an install CD, I already have all scripting, automation, etc. done.

Comment: The answer I would provide is exactly the same.  Use the TKL-Tools to make a quick copy of a running version.

Comment: I would prefer to not have the packages "updated", but be installed at higher versions. Using that method, the packages would still be updated (on the original system).

Comment: IMO, you would make a custom alternate CD using the debian live scripts. http://live.debian.net/manual/html/live-manual.en.html I doubt anyone is going to re-type that guide, or the man pages, but if you have a specific question about a specific step ;)

Comment: Hmmm. I don't see anything in there referring to what I am trying to achieve. I see that you can install third-party .debs and such, but what I need to do is update the packages that get installed in the base system, so that they are installed as the newest version (not updated to the newest version).

Answer (score 0):

though I do not know much about linux, I made a boot disk for ubuntu 11.10 and I was on windows using something called linux live  usb creator (Lili for short) get lili here for free                                                                                                                                                                                                   http://www.linuxliveusb.com/